# Feasibility of a humanoid with both an endo and exoskeleton

Tags: xenobiology

I have been doing some research, but I could not find an answer for this particular question.

Is there any (however so slightly or handwavy) way of explaining the existence of a creature with a humanoid body that has both an endoskeleton to support its body mass and internals, and an exoskeleton (think insect or crustacean like) to protect its flesh and/or skin.

Comment: Something similar to a tortoise is basically what you're looking for with the basic concept of exo+endo skeleton taken into consideration. The body being humanoid along with that might not be feasible though.

Comment: You know which humanoid creature has an internal skeleton and an external protection layer? Human wearing clothes. Or even wearing an armour.

Comment: Don't bother scrolling; it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @VLAZ funny, except i obviously meant an exoskeleton that is permanently attached to the creature and not a suit of ''equippable'' armor

Comment: You just have to make that armor plating biological rather than metalurgical!

Answer (score 17):

Lemming (the user, rather than the small fluffy things, assuming that the user isn't a small fluffy thing, of course) had it right:

[image: A cross section of a tortoise skeleton, showing how limbs, spine and shell are connected.]

(image credit: [Ian Alexander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Turtle_skeleton_cross-section,_labelled_as_infographic.svg))

That's not the only option, of course, but it is most obviously like an exoskeleton. Consider the armadillo, which has a partial armor coat:

[image: Cross section of an armadillo skeleton]

(image credit [Ryan Somma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nine-banded_armadillo_skeleton.jpg))

The armor is made up of [dermal bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermal_bone) with exposed bony [scutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scute) and is protective but not structural in quite the same way that a tortoise shell is. That's probably fine for your needs (you wanted protection) but it isn't quite like an exoskeleton.

The final option would be protective but not bony at all, as demonstrated by the pangolin:

[image: Phillipine pangolin and pup]

(image credit [Gregg Yan](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Philippine_Pangolin_Curled-up_by_Gregg_Yan.jpg))

The scales are keratinous (so like horn or fingernails rather than bone) but are undoubtedly protective.

Unlike tortoises, both armadillos and pangolins are placental mammals, if that was at all important to you.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes and no

There is a good reason to have either an endoskeleton or exoskeleton. From a certain size an exoskeleton is simply too heavy to use. An endoskeleton is much lighter while giving the required structure. At these sizes the skin/fur can also be thick enough to give plenty of protection. So normally it isn't feasible at all to have an exoskeleton at human sizes, making the combination of endo and exoskeleton a folly for any creature of size. They would lose too much energy just moving around to effectively gather resources by hunting/grazing/whatever.

That doesn't mean there isn't some merrit. Instead of an exoskeleton you could have just a few tactical parts of the body shielded. As an example, forearms and a few blades on the back. The reasoning is simple. The endoskeleton has a few structures that do resemble an exoskeleton, only inside. Think of the skull. It isn't there only for structure, but also for protection in much the way an exoskeleton might. In addition many larger creatures still have strange structures that can be offensive, defensive or having little use. Think of antlers on deer for example. They can be used for both offence and defence, though other structures for horns would definitely be better suited. If all that material is instead used on protecting certain tactical areas like an exoskeleton it can still work. The key here is moderation and timing. Deers shed their antlers in the winter. No use to keep such energy hungry things when theres little use and little food.

Comment: "From a certain size an exoskeleton is simply too heavy to use", yes, but it depends on the environment, which is why sea turtles and crabs can grow much larger than spiders. I wonder what kind of environment is needed for an even larger creature. Probably would have to live in a dense fluid, such as mud. Of course, that would bring other problems.

Answer (score 2):

This really is a question about evolutionary biology, not biology alone.

When you compare how endo/exoskeletons form on an evolutionary level, you start to notice a lot of problems with the idea of a dual endo+exoskeleton in a humanoid creature.  Exoskeletons have features that answer questions about their evolution that may or may not be answered when it comes to endoskeletons, which can be seen as a hindrance, but such limitations of reality are a great framework for realism in any fantasy.

When you don't have any real life examples, the type of thing you're looking for probably isn't evolutionarily possible or is incredibly unlikely.  Outside of the rainforest and the sea (in which, convenient for my point, the biodiversity of exoskeletons is more complex), evolution doesn't produce as varied results.  In other words, if something doesn't exist, there's probably good reason for it.

Bottom line is, if you're aiming for ultimate realism, and your story necessitates they have a humanoid form, then your best avenue of approach is to build within/around the evolutionary questions that have been answered for one and not the other, or vice-versa.

If you've gotten this far and what I've written seems like it's making sense, then great. If you're struggling, then take everything I've said so far with a pinch of salt and get ready for the **real bottom line**: realism in fiction/fantasy isn't scientific accuracy, it's pseudoscience that's scientific enough to trick the viewer into believing it.  Whether it's good pseudoscience or actual science, it probably doesn't matter to the scientifically-minded viewer so long as there are consistent principles and models, ones they can intuitively recognize, that don't clash too much with their understanding of the world.  The skill of the writer here is in their ability to creatively build around that intuition and understanding.  All you can do to that end is challenge your own, and gauge/test others' (which is what you're doing here so good job ).